# Add custom key to display units in glossary with siunitx

Tags: glossaries, siunitx

I decided to enrich my list of symbols by adding a unit column with a newly defined key "unit".

```
\glsaddkey
 {unit}
 {}
 {\glsentryunit}
 {\Glsentryunit}
 {\glsunit}
 {\Glsunit}
 {\GLSunit}
```

A new entry looks like

```
\newglossaryentry{insu}{
    type=symbols,
    name=thermal resistance,
    symbol={\ensuremath{R\mathrm{c}}},
    description={ratio of the temperature difference across an insulator and the heat flux for a particular material or assembly of materials},
    unit={\ensuremath\protect\si{\watt}},
}
```

and produces following error with the last curly brace, that closes the `\newglossaryentry`.

```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
\@glo@tmp ->\ensuremath \protect \si {\watt }
```

Moving the code inside the `unit` key, for testing purpose, to the key `symbol` works like a charm, but unfortunately not the intended place.
Changes around the `protect` and `ensuremath` have no effect.
The asterisk variant of `\glsaddkey*` doesn't help either.

What is the conflict between adding a new key to a glossary entry and the `\si` command?

Here a short MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsaddkey
 {unit}
 {}
 {\glsentryunit}
 {\Glsentryunit}
 {\glsunit}
 {\Glsunit}
 {\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}{
 name=Test,
 unit=\si{\meter},
 description=sample description}

%-------------------------

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
\gls{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\ensuremath` and `\protect` with `siunitx`? The error here is happening has `\watt` is undefined outside of `siunitx`'s commands: could you make a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `glossaries` package expands the input for all entries by default. This won't work with 'local' definitions for commands, as used by `siunitx` for unit commands (which can be something entirely different in other context). Possible solutions are to use `\glsnoexpandfields`:

```
\glsnoexpandfields
\newglossaryentry{test}{
 type=symbols,
 name=Test,
 unit=\si{\metre},
 description=sample description}
```

or to inhibit expansion of just the unit

```
\newglossaryentry{test}{
 type=symbols,
 name=Test,
 unit=\unexpanded{\si{\metre}},
 description=sample description}
```

or turn off expansion for the field

```
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
```

Comment: Could I set the unexpanded flag already when defining the `glsaddkey`?

Comment: @Burcardo That's probably one for Nicola Talbot (hopefully will pop up soon!)

Comment: @Burcardo You can put `\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}` before or after `\glsaddkey`. You just need to make sure it's set before any instance of `\newglossaryentry` where the expansion needs to be suppressed. The starred version of `\glsaddkey` forces expansion on for that key even if `\glsnoexpandfields` is used (but can later be overridden with `\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}`).