# SI unit in acronym glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have a question. I want to use SI unit X in my acronym definitions. For example:

```
\newacronym{M}{\si{\Molar}}{molar}
```

Sadly this doesn't work. Is there a way to do use SI units in the acronym definition? I know about the possibility to use `\newglossaryentry`, but I want to have all my acronyms in one list.
When I remove all the `\si` parts, it works. But I'd like to have the spacing right.

Comment: [Add custom key to display units in glossary with siunitx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192336)

Comment: @Johannes_B I thought I'd seen something like this before :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for the link! ive already seen this thread and wanted to ask, if there is a possibility to do it with newacronym. there are just a few acronyms with si units. i dont want to add an additional line, i want to use si units in my acronym definition

Comment: http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,73945.html#73945

Comment: Can you show a minimal working example that let's us reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It would help if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that people can work with.)

The problem is caused by the default expansion that's performed when the entry is defined. This can be fixed by using `\glsnoexpandfields` to switch off the expansion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}

\makeglossaries

\glsnoexpandfields

\newacronym{M}{\si{\Molar}}{molar}

\begin{document}

\gls{M}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Alternative, protect the fragile commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{M}{\protect\si{\protect\Molar}}{molar}

\begin{document}

\gls{M}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\si` is not fragile (LaTeX3-based => `\protected\def`)

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, it's just `\Molar` that needs protecting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem with `\newacronym[sort=M]{M}{\unexpanded{\si{\Molar}}}{molar}`