# Symbol Glossarie: Showing the unit instead of the name

Tags: symbols, glossaries, units

I am using a symbol glossaries looking like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{Symb:V}{
    name=\ensuremath{V},
    description={Volume},
    symbol=\si{\milli\metre\cubed},
    sort=lat:V,
    type=Symb
}
```

Usually I use \gls{Symb:V) to show V. Now I want to show the unit mm^3 instead. How can I do this?

I checked google, but I could not find the correct question to type in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is straight-forward. But perhaps these links ([#1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units) and [#2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192336/add-custom-key-to-display-units-in-glossary-with-siunitx)) could be of interest to you as well.

```
\documentclass{book}                           
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Symb:V}{
    name=\ensuremath{V},
    description={Volume},
    symbol=\si{\milli\metre\cubed},
    type=symbols,
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    First use of \gls{Symb:V}, of \glsdesc{Symb:V} and finally of \glssymbol{Symb:V}.

    \printsymbols
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just the moment I found an answer as well. Whats the between \glsentrysymbol and \glssymbol?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
\gls{Symb:Q}            & \glsentrysymbol{Symb:Q} & \glsentrydesc{Symb:Q} \\
```